# Sending & receiving Bulk Sms in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

So I read almost every topic on sending & receiving sms in android. My Current situation is, I am able to use my code on a Froyo Device where as the same code fails on Samsung GT P3100 having ICS.
Fails : I can see the messages as SENT in my logcat, but when there are bulk messages for instance 40 messages, few random messages go missing. The same is observed in reception.
 Any kind of help or suggestions would be really helpful. Below is my code

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="3.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.IncomingSmsCaptureApp" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />

            <data android:port="5000" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Activity_Login_From"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Activity_Main_Form"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Activity_GatePass_Entry_Form"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Activity_GRN_Details_Form"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Farmer_Details_Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Item_Details_Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Attribute_Details_Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.Cashier_Entry_Tab"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

SMS.java which does the sending of the message

```
public class SMS {

Context mContext;
boolean smsstatus, receivedflag;
String ORG_ID, Tpin;
int is_Exception=0;
Common_Functions fun;
public static String sms_reply="false",reply_msg="";
UtilClass _util;
ProgressDialog pdauth;
public SMS(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    fun=new Common_Functions(mContext);
    _util=new UtilClass(mContext);
}

public void sendSMS(final String phoneNumber, final String message,final String rec_no,String db_msg) {
    final String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    smsstatus = false;
    receivedflag = false;
    System.out.println("Inside Sent SMS " + phoneNumber + " " + message);


    final PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    final PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---


    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
//  mContext.registerReceiver(smsstatusDeliverRecver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
     Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override

            public void run() {

              try {
                  mContext.registerReceiver(smsstatusSentRecver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
                  Thread.sleep(2000);

                  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage("+"+phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI,
                        deliveredPI);

                System.out.println("message sent ... " + message);


                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("Sending Thread Exception-->>"+e.toString());

                }

            }

           });
     background.start();

    try {
        System.out.println("Calling Thread" + message);
        WaitTask wt = new WaitTask(message,rec_no,db_msg);
        wt.start();
        /*WaitTaskUser waitask=new WaitTaskUser(phoneNumber,message,rec_no,db_msg);
        waitask.execute();*/


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception  =  " + e.getMessage());
    }


}
/*BroadcastReceiver smsstatusDeliverRecver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            System.out.println("Delievery status ...RESULT_OK.... " + getResultCode());
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            System.out.println("Delievery status ...RESULT_CANCELED.... " +getResultCode());
            break;
        }
    }
};*/

BroadcastReceiver smsstatusSentRecver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        switch (getResultCode()) {

        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            smsstatus = true;
            receivedflag = true;
            //_util.writeToSDFile1(message+" RESULT_OK Flag--->"+smsstatus);
            System.out.println("smsstatus :RESULT_OK " + smsstatus+"receivedflag-->>"+receivedflag);
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            smsstatus= false;
            receivedflag = true;
            //_util.writeToSDFile1(message+" RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE Flag--->"+smsstatus);

            System.out.println("smsstatus : RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE" + smsstatus+"receivedflag-->>"+receivedflag);
            // UtilClass.printsystem("result Fail : " + count);
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            smsstatus = false;
            receivedflag = true;
            //_util.writeToSDFile1(message+" RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE Flag--->"+smsstatus);
            System.out.println("smsstatus : RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE" + smsstatus+"receivedflag-->>"+receivedflag);
            // UtilClass.printsystem("result No Service : " + count);
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            smsstatus = false;
            receivedflag = true;
            //_util.writeToSDFile1(message+" RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:--->"+smsstatus);
            System.out.println("smsstatus :RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU " + smsstatus+"receivedflag-->>"+receivedflag);
            // UtilClass.printsystem("result NULL PDU : " + count);
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            smsstatus = false;
            receivedflag = true;
        //  _util.writeToSDFile1(message+" RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:--->"+smsstatus);
            System.out.println("smsstatus :RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF " + smsstatus+"receivedflag-->>"+receivedflag);
            // UtilClass.printsystem("result RADIO OFF : " + count);
            break;
        }
    }
};

class WaitTask extends Thread {

    String Message,rec_No,db_MSG;
    int Count;

    public WaitTask(String message,String rec_no,String db_msg) {

        Message = message;
        //Count = count;
        rec_No=rec_no;
        db_MSG=db_msg;
    }

    public void run() {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("start--->>"+start);
        long end = start + 60 * 100000;
        System.out.println("end--->>"+end);
        try{
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {

            if (receivedflag == true) {

                if (smsstatus == true) {
                    System.out.println("Received Response " + smsstatus);
                        sms_reply="true";
                        SQLConnect db=new SQLConnect(mContext);
                        db.open();

                        try {
                            String sb_code="";
                            if(!Message.startsWith("START"))
                            {
                                String[] arr=_util.split(Message, "#");

                                try {

                                    sb_code=Message.substring(Message.lastIndexOf("#")+1,Message.length());
                                    System.out.println("IN SMS sb_code--->>"+sb_code);
                                    int code =Integer.parseInt(sb_code,10);
                                    //  String query="delete FROM SENTBOX WHERE SENTBOX_CODE = "+code+" and TPIN = '"+_util.getUserData_atPosition(mContext,15,Activity_Login_From.Username)+"'";
                                    String query="UPDATE SENTBOX set SENT_STATUS='10' , SYNC_TYPE = 'GSM' WHERE SENTBOX_CODE = "+code+"";   
                                    System.out.println("IN SMS Delete Query--->>"+query);
                                        db.ExecuteSql(query);

                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                finally{
                                    if(db!=null)
                                        db.close();
                                }

                            }

                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finally{
                            if(db!=null)
                                db.close();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Breaking thread: " + Message);
                    break;
                } else {

                    sms_reply="false";

                }
            }
            //mContext.unregisterReceiver(smsstatusRecver);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally{
        if(smsstatusSentRecver.isOrderedBroadcast())
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(smsstatusSentRecver);

    }

    }

}
```

}

My Receiver

```
public class IncomingSmsCaptureApp extends BroadcastReceiver  {
UtilClass util;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String OrgId = "", CellNo = "";
Context mContext;
Common_Functions fun;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("Message Received...");
    util = new UtilClass(context);
    fun=new Common_Functions(mContext);
    mContext=context;
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String[] Messages=null;
    String port=mContext.getString(R.string.SMS_PORT);
    String url=intent.getDataString();//SMS://Localhost:Port
    if(url.indexOf(port)!=-1)
    {

             if (bundle != null) 
             {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                Messages= new String[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                    String msg = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    Messages[i]=msg;
                    System.out.println("Message Received..." + msg);

                }


                for(int i=0;i<Messages.length;i++)
                {
                    fun.insertIntoDb_inbox(Messages[i],"GSM",mContext);
                }
                fun.PrecessInboxMessages(mContext);

                abortBroadcast();

             }



    }

}

public boolean isDataBaseExist() {
    File dbFile = new File(Activity_Login_From.DB_PATH
            + Activity_Login_From.DatabaseName);
    System.out.print("DataBase Exist " + dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

}

Comment: "where as the same code fails" -- this is a useless description of your symptoms.

Comment: pardon me? I did not get you!

Comment: What does "where as the same code fails" mean to you? How are we supposed to help you when we have no idea what "fails" means? Does "fails" mean that you had a crash? If so, please post the stack trace. Does "fails" mean something else? If so, what? It is not our job to pry these sorts of details out of your head. It is your job to give us enough information to help you.

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the description. By fail I mean Messages go missing. Its like I am sending transactions from my device to the server and the server sends back a response. The server then again sends the same transaction to the same device. Each transaction message is split into 4 different messages, so suppose I create 10 transactions and send them, 40 messages are created and sent. Any message which goes missing in the entire scenario proves to be very costly at my end. :(